# Adding column values to octave bar diagram

Tags: plot, bar-chart, octave

I'm making new bar diagram in my OCTAVE application. Because of the better readings I want to add actual values for each bar. The actual values of each bar column should be located on the high Y=50% and centrally centered with each bar column. I have search over the google, but I didnt found any real example of values over the bar columns.

My example made in paint, how should look:
[image]

Picture above is a example how should look - for example purposes there are RED colored values of the each bar column.

Code of the plotting of this bar diagram:

```
subplot(5, 1, 5);
y2 = [data1; data2; data3; data4];
x = [1 ,2 ,3, 4];
labels = ["DATANAME1"; "DATANAME2"; "DATANAME3"; "DATANAME4"];
bar (x, y2, 0.5, 'facecolor', [0, 0.5, 1]);
set(gca, 'xticklabel', labels);  
title("Something [%]");
xlabel('XLABEL');
ylabel("%");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`text`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/text.html) command for putting any text on/over any plot.

Here's my suggestion, I slightly re-worked your code:

```matlab
% Data
x = [1, 2, 3, 4];
y2 = [2; 52; 3; 43];

% Original plot
bar(x, y2, 0.5, 'FaceColor', [0, 0.5, 1]);
labels = ['DATANAME1'; 'DATANAME2'; 'DATANAME3'; 'DATANAME4'];
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', labels);  
title('Something [%]');
xlabel('XLABEL');
ylabel('%');

% Additional plot
y = max(y2) / 2;              % "located on the high Y=50%"
values = [num2str(y2) repelem(' %', 4, 1)];
text( x - 0.1, ...            % x values to put text (some negative displacement for "centrally centered with each bar column")
      repelem(y, 4, 1), ...   % y values to put text (four times y)
      values, ...             % Actual values as text plus "%" to put
      'Color', 'r', ...       % Red text
      'FontWeight', 'bold');  % Bold text
```

The output then looks like this:

[image: Output]

I used Octave 5.1.0, the `repelem` command might not be available before Octave 5.x, but there are alternatives to achieve what `repelem` does.

Notice, the construction of `values` (only) works, because `y2` is a column vector. Otherwise, adding the "%" to each value in `y2` might be a bit more complicated.

Hope that helps!